# Checkbox with Thymeleaf - SpringInputCheckboxFieldTagProcessor

Tags: spring-mvc, checkbox, thymeleaf

I am trying to add a checkbox to my form. While I am creating a user, the checkbox works fine. However, while I am editing a user, I get this error:

```
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputCheckboxFieldTagProcessor'
```

And here is the code:
(Error is in `<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{isEnabled}" checked/>`)

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Enable User</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{isEnabled}" checked/>
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Lock User</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{isLocked}" checked/>
    </div>
</div>
```

What could be an issue here?

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the error.

Comment: Please include the code form-backing object and your endpoint as well.

Comment: Please can you add the code of your entity(POJO).